# How can I use signalR with unity for client server communication

Tags: unity-game-engine, signalr

Can Any one tell me How can we use signalR with Unity For Client server communication.

Im getting error in my code.

The code is as below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;

public class SignalR : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}



    public class Client
    {
        private readonly string _platform;
        private readonly HubConnection _connection;
        private readonly IHubProxy _proxy;

        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnMessageReceived;

        public Client(string platform)
        {
            _platform = platform;
            _connection = new HubConnection("http://192.168.1.103");
            _proxy = _connection.CreateHubProxy("Chat");
        }

        public void Connect()
        {
             _connection.Start();

            _proxy.On("messageReceived", (string platform, string message) =>
                      {
                if (OnMessageReceived != null)
                    OnMessageReceived(this, string.Format("{0}: {1}", platform, message));
            });

            Send("Connected");
        }

        public void Send(string message)
        {
            return _proxy.Invoke("Send", _platform, message);
        }
    }
```

This is my client side code.I have added ell’s in my assets for signalR.

The error details are as below:
Internal compiler error. See the console log for more information. output was:
Unhandled Exception: Mono.CSharp.InternalErrorException: Assets/SignalR.cs(30,24): Client.Client(string) ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Connection' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client, Version=2.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.MonoType:GetMethodsByName (string,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,bool,System.Type)
  at System.MonoType.GetMethods (BindingFlags bindingAttr) [0x00000] in :0

Thanks In Advance!!

Comment: Have you considered pulling apart the m$ generated javascript based proxy classes when using signalR in a web app to see what code that geneerates ? ... maybe that might help lend some light on the subject matter.